# ODBC 3 Multiple Statements vs Multiple Connections

Tags: sql, multithreading, windows, sql-server

So right now I have a single thread to handle all the requests for the database. Let's say I have 400 requests per second for logins / logouts / other stuff, and 400 requests per second which are only related to items (move them, update them, remove them, etc).

Obviously, the problem is that If I want to load an item from the database, but the database is currently processing a login request, then there's gonna be a delay. And I want it to be instant, that's why I wanted to create another thread, exclusive to process item requests, and the other thread to process logins/logouts, etc.

Microsoft says this:

> > 1: Have multiple statement handles on a single connection handle, with a single thread for each statement handle.
> >
> > 2: Have multiple connection handles, with a single statement handle and single thread for each connection handle.

- What are exactly the differences on both approaches? I obviously need to fetch data and insert/update in both threads at the same time.
- Will this 2 threads vs 1 approach speed up things?

Both threads will work exclusive in different SQL tables (ie the thread for the items will only use ITEMS_TABLE, it will never use the LOGIN_TABLE and vice-versa)

Currently I'm using the following functions (C++):

```
SQLSetEnvAttr with SQL_OV_ODBC3
SQLConnect

SQLAllocHandle
SQLBindParameter
SQLExecDirect
```